# Is it possible to install github repository on Google Cloud Composer

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

As title, we can set pypi packages in **requirements.txt** file and use the command

```
gcloud beta composer environments update env_name --update-pypi-packages-from-file requirements.txt --location location
```

to update the cloud composer environment.

But does it support to install custom github repo in requirements.txt? I've tried adding the link like:

```
pkg_name @ git+ssh://git@github.com/my_account/pkg_repo.git#master
```

and it doesn't work.

Thanks!

**Update:**
I have a workaround solution is to put the library into plugins. But the best strategy in our case is to install a package from github I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not support to install custom libraries this way. [In docs here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies) you can see how  `--update-pypi-packages` is intended to be used only with libraries which are in the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.org/):

> You can install Python dependencies from the Python Package Index
>   through the Google Cloud Platform Console or by making a partial
>   update request to the environment using the gcloud command-line tool.

You have three alternative options:

> Install a local Python library.
>
> Use the plugins feature.
>
> Use the KubernetesPodOperator.

Installing using a [local Python library](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-local) is quite straightforward:
1. In your composer GCS bucket, in the dags folder create a `dependencies` folder and inside there add your library modules (don't forget to add the necessary "**init**.py" file(s)).
2. Then simply do something like:

```
from dependencies import your_module
```

Comment: That works great for DAG dependencies, but what about plugins (sensors, operators) dependencies? adding a /plugins/dependencies folder with the required module doesn't get picked up and importing from `dependencies.module` results in an error